# Questions about gradient descent and local optima

Tags: gradient-descent, optimal

I'm starting out learning about gradient descent, and have a couple of conceptual questions.

1. I noticed a common pitfall of gradient descent is getting stuck in the local optima. How can this be avoided (while still being considered gradient descent)?
2. If a function alternates up and down infinitely across the x axis, does that mean it has an infinite amount of local optima?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Comments. Your point (1) is why *convex* problems tend to be solvable why non-convex problems can be a complete disaster. The answer to (2) is yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. run it multiple times from different starting points. Momentum. Pretraining. those are the methods I can think of.
2. It's the shape of the error function that is important and that probably won't be a sinusoid. If you are fitting a sinusoid with squared error, then your function would be nice and convex with no local mina

Comment: I don't understand your answer to the second part. I know a function like that is unlikely, but I would still like to know if what that means for the local optima. I understand maxima and minima are peaks and valleys, but what if there are an infinite amount of peaks and valleys? Does that mean there are infinite optima?

Comment: Imagine that this function has minimum at 0. That picture would mean that you are fitting a function with one parameter (x axis) and the error corresponding to this size of a parameter is on a y axis. In that case yes, you will have infinitely many local minima.